# My batch save/load function wont work properly

Tags: batch-file, load, save

So I am experimenting and trying to get better at using batch but I'm stuck on an issue, and I cant figure it out. The save/load allows the user to input a password and save it to the blah.blah, then later load it using the password. The problem is I want the program to recognize if the user has a password and if they dont, it will give them the option to exit or make a new password.

```
:passwordwant
cls
set /p "passwant=Enter your new password: "
(
echo %passwant%
)>save.sav
goto :passwordload
pause >nul

:passwordload
cls
echo Enter password to enter the programme
set /p "pass=>" 
if %pass%== %passwant% goto :home
<save.sav(
set /p pass=
)
```

Comment: So you just want to see if the save.sav file exists?

Comment: Pretty much yeah @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if exist` to determine if a file exists (or `if not exist` to determine if it doesn't).

```
if not exist save.sav (
    echo Password not found

    REM If you're using Windows XP or earlier, you need to use set /p instead of choice
    choice /c:NQ /M "Press N to create a password. Press Q to quit."
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :passwordwant
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 exit /b
)
```